# Gradle: How to merge two .tar files without extracting their contents?

Tags: gradle

After reading Gradle's user guide and searching through the internet I still can't find a way to merge two .tar files without extracting their contents.
The reason I can't extract their contents is because some files lose their permissions.

I was hoping something in the lines of:

```
FileTree someTar = tarTree(resources.gzip('file1.tar.gz'))
FileTree otherTar = tarTree(resources.gzip('file2.tar.gz'))
FileTree result = someTar + otherTar
```

But it doesn't work... does anyone has some idea or insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
task mergedTar(type: Tar) {
    from tarTree(...)
    from tarTree(...)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, although it definitely merges both files, unfortunately it still extracts temporarily their contents before merging. I'm gonna accept your response because it might be useful form some people in the future.
Regarding my problem, I'll try a different approach :)